# How to generate a string containing private and public key in PhP?

Tags: php

I saw this code:

```
<?php
class MyEncryption
{

    public $pubkey = '...public key here...';
    public $privkey = '...private key here...';

    public function encrypt($data)
    {
        if (openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $this->pubkey))
            $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
        else
            throw new Exception('Unable to encrypt data. Perhaps it is bigger than the key size?');

        return $data;
    }

    public function decrypt($data)
    {
        if (openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $decrypted, $this->privkey))
            $data = $decrypted;
        else
            $data = '';

        return $data;
    }
}


?>
```

What are samples of public_key? What kind of public key should be put on $pubkey? Should it be base_64encoded or not? How do I generate one?

I added:

```
$privKey = openssl_pkey_new();
```

And all I got is $privKey==false

Comment: Is this a specific script or your own work?

Comment: from where, you got this code ?

Comment: I got this from stackoverflow. I am learning.

Comment: I said I saw a code. No I didn't write this.

Comment: I just want to use a simple private and public. No need for anything complicated.

Comment: The code appears to have been posted previously in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2806742 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4484258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys have to be generated together, as the public key is the "non-secret" key that can encrypt information so that only the private key is able to decrypt it. This is an example of [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_encryption).

If openssl_pkey_new fails (it will not return the key itself, only a resource that you can use to retrieve the actual keys), see the [examples and links to alternatives](http://no.php.net/openssl_pkey_new) in the comment section of the manual page.

And no, the keys should not base64-encoded. This is only done to the encrypted **data** in your methods. The reason that this is done in the class is probably because the original author wanted to transfer the encrypted data through some sort of non-binary-safe environment.